How to create form field using Pdfium library
An annotation can be created using FPDFPage_CreateAnnot with type FPDF_ANNOT_SUBTYPE_WIDGET.
But does not see any method to set FormField to the created annotation.
only see the following methods like FPDF_SetFormFieldHighlightColor, FPDF_SetFormFieldHighlightAlpha
But how to create form field like FPDF_FORMFIELD_TEXTFIELD,FPDF_FORMFIELD_CHECKBOX,FPDF_FORMFIELD_RADIOBUTTON... etc using pdfium
Checked pdfium documentations

As part of pdfium build config do see  # Set true to enable experimental Skia backend.
pdf_use_skia = false

https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/

PDFium does provide complete editing of pdf's, had implemented all kinds of editing operation. This was the only missing peace of puzzle which I found. there is an open issue and which require a contribution, mostly i will start on that https://bugs.chromium.org/p/pdfium/issues/detail?id=2137
